# How do you Query Select find a span in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this span and I'm trying to use JQuery to get the value within the span using find query selector.

```
<div class='form'>
<span name='spanValue'>1</span>
</div>
```

my jquery

```
var spanValue = $('.form').find('span[name="spanValue"]').val();
```

for some reason this does not get the value when running and I'm not sure why. Even doing this doesn't work

```
var spanValue = $('.form').find('[name="spanValue"]').val();
```

Comment: Did you tried $('.form').find('span[name="spanValue"]').text(); ?
.val() is for input type elements this is an element with text as a content.

Comment: that worked, thanks!